# Access EZVIZ IP Camera - Streaming URL - Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera

I tried to access an EZVIZ IP Camera via WIFI, but i got this error in my python code:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'.

Also I tried to find URL Streaming in EZVIZ Studio, in the menu: "Access Configuration", but page doesn't load. I think URL Streaming is wrong, but i'm not sure what is the problem.

This is the code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.12:554/h264_stream")

while True:
    ret, frame = img.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

img.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- i put "admin" because i saw it in others recomendations, but i don't know where to change it and what exactly it is.
- "password" is the 6 digit camera access code, for example: ABCDEF. It is on the camera.
- 192.168.1.12:554 is the ip camera with RTSP channel, i've also tried with 192.168.1.12 and 192.168.1.12:8000.
- i put h264_stream because of this page: https://www.ispyconnect.com/camera/ezviz , according to the camera model, but i'm not sure it is okey.

Comment: Please share the exact error message and stack tace. [ask]

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the message: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: You should check `img`, `img.isOpened()`, `ret` and `frame` before calling `imshow`. If `read()` doesn't return a valid frame, keep on reading a while. Depending on what you observe, please add more debug information. Please add new information to the question above (edit), not by adding a comment!

Comment: Thank you for your help Markus. I followed your suggestion and notice that RTSP protocol was disabled in EZVIZ app, because "frame" return None.